# Link on a webpage to local application?

Tags: hyperlink

I was wondering if I could have a web link to a local application form my webpage.

I'm almost certain that this is not possible, but I'm just wondering.

For example, a music player web application which has a link to buy that song in iTunes, or any other local music application.

Upon the link being clicked, the user's local iTunes application would be launched.

I have seen this done before, but I would imagine that the application needs support for this, already.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Done.  Tell me if you need any more clarification.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. What exactly do you expect to happen when such a link is clicked on? Application launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally done by using protocol handlers. For instance, AIM will register with the OS to handle aim:// URLs, and that allows a web page to link to those URLs, and when they're clicked, AIM will open. So you're right in saying that the application has to support it for it to work.

Comment: The application and the OS need to support this.

Comment: Indeed. All modern OSs do though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.  Is there any good resource of supported applications?  Or, should I just find out the applications I like, and check if they have the support?

Comment: Well, you haven't really said what you want to do with this... There probably are lists of protocols handled by applications on various OSs. I used to have a Preferences Pane (for System Preferences on Mac OS X) that would show all the ones registered on my computer, but I don't seem to have it anymore, and don't remember what it was called.